# Make bold even numbers which are multiple of 3

Tags: php

I have to echo all even numbers from 1 to 100, and in this list, the numbers which are multiple of 3 should be in bold. So far I can show to list of even numbers, but I can't find a way to make bold the multiples of 3.

Here's the code for showing even numbers:

```
<?php

$evenumber=2;

while($evenumber<101) {
echo $evenumber."<br>";
$evenumber=$evenumber+2;
}

?>
```

(and it works)

Now I'm struggling using if and else statemens to no result:

```
<?php


$evenarray = array();

for ($evenumber=2;$evenumber<101;) {

if( 'dont know what to put here' )
    {
        echo "<strong>".$evenumber."</strong><br>";
        $evenumber=$evenumber+2;
    }

else
    {
         echo $evenumber."<br>";
         $evenumber=$evenumber+2;
    }


    }


?>
```

any help?...

Comment: There's a mathematical operator that does exactly what you need. For example, what happens if you divide a multiple of 3 by 3, as opposed to a non-multiple of 3?

Comment: Use the `%` operator to test divisibility of numbers. Also, give this a whirl: `foreach(range(2,100,2) as $n) echo $n." ";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using modulo? Consider this example:

```
for($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
    if($x % 2 == 0) {
        echo "$x <br/>";
    } elseif($x % 3 == 0) {
        echo "<b>$x</b> <br/>";
    }
}
```